# Why can I get the FAILED:Invalid table alias or column reference ‘ ’: (possible column names are: line) when I queried in Hive?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table which struct is:

```
line      string
```

and the content is:

```
product_id product_date orderattribute1 orderattribute2 orderattribute3     orderattribute4 ciiquantity ordquantity price
1 2014-09 2 1 1 1 1 3 153
1 2014-01 2 1 1 1 1 1 153
1 2014-04 2 2 1 1 1 1 164
1 2014-02 2 1 1 1 3 4 162
1 2014-07 2 1 1 1 9 23 224
1 2014-08 2 1 1 1 1 7 216
1 2014-03 2 1 1 1 3 13 180
1 2014-08 2 2 1 1 4 6 171
1 2014-05 2 1 1 1 3 7 180
....
(19000 lines omited)
```

the total price of every `line` above is ordquantity*price

I want to get the total price of every `month` like this:

```
month   sum
201401  ****
201402  ****
```

Accoding to just 10 lines in the table above,the sum of month 201408 is 7*216+6*171 which is derived from (1 2014-08 2 1 1 1 1 7 216 and 1 2014-08 2 1 1 1 1 7 216).

I use the code:

```
create table product as select sum(ordquantity*price) as sum from text3 group by product_date;
```

and I got the FAILED:

```
FAILED:Invalid table alias or column reference 'product_date': (possible column names are: line)
```

I am not familiar with Hive,I don't know how to solv the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you just create the table with correct schema? Well in case, if you didn't

```
CREATE TABLE product
(product_id INT 
product_date STRING
orderattribute1 INT
orderattribute2 INT
orderattribute3 INT
orderattribute4 INT
ciiquantity INT
ordquantity INT
price INT)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

And the code for your requirment,

```
SELECT product_date, SUM(ordquantity*price) FROM product
GROUP BY product_date;
```

Hope I answered your question. Yippee!!

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer!